# Kinect 2: Silouhette distance between fixed points (shoulders, hips etc)

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'll be straightforward, I need, after monitoring a silhouette with kinect, I need to know the distance between some arbitrary points like head, shoulders, hips and so on.

Here's what I need, but can't find anything useful or concise on google. I'm using kinect SDK at the moment.

I've seen someone using a 2 time strategy, making the user take a photo from front then from side and making an ellipse but it doesn't seems what I'm looking for.

Can anyone help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Body Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.bodyindexframe.aspx) can be used to extract a person from a scene and ignoring the background (as you have shown in the image above).

The [Skeleton Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.skeletonstream.aspx) can be used to detect skeleton joints of a tracked human.

You have to enable both these streams simultaneously. Then for measuring head For example, start counting the pixels of Body Index on both sides of Head Joint came from Skeleton stream. Now you just need to convert those pixels in metrics.
You can use the same approach for neck, shoulders, hips, chest etc.